# Receive/send Transactions latency

Tags: bitcoin-core, transactions, bitcoind, unconfirmed-transactions

I am on Ubuntu 16.04, with the latest version of Bitcoin Core, synced and working.

I would like to know why is there a little delay of approximately 1 sec, sometimes more, before a received transaction appear on the console when we run for instance `bitcoind -printoconsole`, if I check the tx on blockchain.com for instance, I can see that the transaction were received 1 or 2 sec before I even see it on my node, why is there a delay ? I have try on another ubuntu server with a super fast connection and it's the same thing. By the way, it's the same thing when I send a Tx, it's submitted and appear on the network 1-2 secs after.

So my question is why is there such a delay even on a node ? Is it possible to reduce it ?

I have already asked the same question on the bitcoin repo on github and someone told me that it is an intentional delay against attackers, but what I don't understand is why blockchain has access to it before node ? If they can it mean that we can too right ?

Just like when few years ago and even months, some brainwallet were swipped within milliseconds.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question, your latency compared to blockchain.info is motivated to the blockchain.ifo use the node distributed to the world and you have only the one node.

I have read [this reasearch](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1709.02489.pdf) where write this

> In  any  peer-to-peer  system,  dierent  nodes  will  receive  thesame data at different times.  Blockchain.info uses a geographi-﻿cally distributed set of nodes to obtain relatively accurate times-tamps.   BlockSci is a single-node system,  so its timestamps in-evitably lag those of blockchain.info. Based on 2 weeks of mempooldata recorded by our AWS node in theus-east-1ddata center, wefound that our timestamps lag blockchain.info’s timestamps byan average of 16 seconds and a standard deviation of 4 seconds.Any BlockSci user can perform a similar measurement and apply auniform correction to eliminate the average lag, but of course the﻿variance will remain.

Comment: Okay I understand, I will read the research, thank you !